# LoopBack filter "where and " return wrong/same result in any value

Tags: node.js, rest, loopbackjs, strongloop

This is what in loopback docs said about using `and` operators

**rest:** `?filter[where][and][0][title]=My%20Post&filter[where][and][1][content]=Hello`

I tried:

```
count?filter{"where":[{"and"}[{"user_id":"5a6840ddb2b58b07cca3c680"},{"post_id":"4444"}]} //post_id:4444 is not exit
```

and

```
count?filter[where][and][0][user_id]="5a6840ddb2b58b07cca3c680"&filter[where][and][1][post_id]="5a6253bdcf975122dcf11dd8"
```

and many other forms
but the result is `count: 12` but should return 0 in 4444 or any wrong post_id.
also, post_id and user_id are relational Objectid.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the filter and just use a where. (Thanks to Raymond Feng for helping me with this.)

Comment: Dear @raymond-camden, Thank you so much, this was tired me.